# flask-restful how to fetch GET parameter

Tags: flask, flask-restful

i'm wondering how to fetch `GET` parameters in flask-restful like his
`/hi/city?=NY`

i can do like this `/hi/city/NY` using `/hi/city/<string:ccc>` but how to do so with `/hi/city?=NY` .

i checked the documentation and it seems like using `reqparse` : http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html but still couldn't figure out how

Comment: Do you mean `/hi?city=NY`?

Comment: @dirn yes GET parameters whatever the url

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `RequestParser` bundled along with Flask-Restful.

```
from flask_restful import reqparse

class YourAPI(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('city')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        city_value = args.get('city')
```

By default, the request parser searches json, form fields and query string (as it is in your case) for the key named `city`. The variable `city_value` will have the value passed in the API request.

Comment: update from [flask-restful docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html), the request parser has been deprecated, as stated from the website: 
> The whole request parser part of Flask-RESTful is slated for removal and will be replaced by documentation on how to integrate with other packages that do the input/output stuff better (such as marshmallow).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `request.args.get('key')`